# Synchronizing application state while joining a Phoenix Channel (or other pubsub)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ets, phoenix-channels

I am building a collaborative drawing board (eg r/place): there is a grid of pixels which users can change at any time and the pixel updates get propagated to all other users online. I want to use Phoenix Channels to broadcast the pixel changes.

My question is about how to *correctly* send the current application state when the user connects to the service.

Currently I have an ETS table holding the drawing board state. I can update this table in `MyChannel.handle_in/3` before broadcasting any pixel writes.

My fear is that *in between* reading the current state in `MyChannel.join`, and the user being subscribed to the Channel by Phoenix, a different process updates the state.

The user would get a stale version of the application state, and they wouldn't be subscribed yet, so they wouldn't get the update through the Channel either.

To solve this, I think I need a way to atomically read the current state and then subscribe to the pubsub, ensuring that no messages get written to the ETS table or the Channel for that time period. I guess a lock? Is that Elixirey, or is there another way?

Answer (score 2):

While writing this question I had a look at Chris McCoord's [ElixirConf 2015 training materials](https://github.com/chrismccord/elixirconf_training/blob/master/web/channels/document_channel.ex#L11). I thought there was that same race condition in that example, but it turns out there isn't! That channel holds the solution.

In that example,in the `Channel.join` function process sends itself an :after_join message, which *later on* (after being subscribed) will
trigger handle_info({:after_join...}) to read the application state and sends that to the user.

**The key is to query the application state after being subscribed.**

And also always change the state before publishing.

I say always because I went through every of the 24 possible orderings of:

- reading the state,
- mutating the state,
- subscribing to the channel
- publishing to the channel

and confirmed reading the state after subscribing, combined with
updating the state before publishing, was guaranteed not to have data loss.
 [Here my work in a gist](https://gist.github.com/amedeedaboville/2bc6bc5c9d50f343a46bc6ad3864167f).

It does lead to 4 possible conditions where a state change is seen twice, but that is a lot easier to deal with than data loss.